# Given $\Phi(t)\in M_{n}(\mathcal{C}^1)$, non-singular for each $t\in\Bbb{R}$, exists only one $A(t)$ s.t. $\Phi$ is fundamental to $x'=Ax$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here, $M_n(\mathcal{C}^1)$ is the space of the $n\times n$ matrix of differentiable functions.

To prove uniqueness I did:

Suppose that $\Phi(t)$ is the fundamental matrix of $x'=A(t)x$ and of $x'=B(t)x$. Then, $A(t)\Phi(t)=\Phi'(t)=B(t)\Phi(t)$, as $\Phi$ is non-singular, $A(t)\Phi=B(t)\Phi\Leftrightarrow A(t)=B(t).$

How do I prove existence?

Answer (score 0):

To the existence, $A\Phi=\Phi'\Leftrightarrow A=\Phi'(\Phi^{-1})$